# Is there a different way to use methods of another class?

Tags: java, selenium

I fixed it. I extended the `AbstractPage` where the methods are. At first I would get a Test class must have a singular no-Argument constructor. Then I realized that in the @Before the driver variable and startup variable made problems after I removed those and just called the open `chromedriver()` method and the `openhomepage` method eclipse was happy and it allowed me to run the tests and remove the part where I had to call the class then the method. Thanks for the help.

```
package seleniumTests.QA.com;


public class Testforpage {

private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void SetUp() {
    AbstractPage startUp = new AbstractPage(driver);
    driver = startUp.openChromeDriver();
    onRegistrationPage = new RegistrationPage(driver);
    onRegistrationPage.openHomePage(driver);
}

@Test
public void register() {
    onRegistrationPage.clickOn(onRegistrationPage.REGISTRATION_LINK);
    assertEquals(onRegistrationPage.getURL(),"http://demoqa.com/registration/");
    // Write first name**
    onRegistrationPage.type(onRegistrationPage.FIRST_NAME_INPUT, "User");
    // Write last name
    onRegistrationPage.type(onRegistrationPage.LAST_NAME_INPUT, "Dev");
    // click marrital status
    onRegistrationPage.clickOn(onRegistrationPage.MARITAL_STATUS_BUTTON); 
    // click hobby
    onRegistrationPage.clickOn(onRegistrationPage.HOBBY_BUTTON);
```

This is how the code looks now.

```
  public class Testforpage extends AbstractPage {


   public Testforpage() {
     }

@Before
public void SetUp() {
    driver = openChromeDriver();
    openHomePage(driver);
}

@Test
public void register() {
    clickOn(REGISTRATION_LINK);
    assertEquals(getURL(),"http://demoqa.com/registration/");
    // Write first name**
    type(FIRST_NAME_INPUT, "User");
    // Write last name
    type(LAST_NAME_INPUT, "Dev");
    // click marrital status
    clickOn(MARITAL_STATUS_BUTTON);
```

Comment: I would propose that, at least, the original (or last revision) be posted as the "hold" version. We have two answers that now make no sense in the absence of the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't delete your own question? I don't think there's a reputation requirement for deleting your own questions/answers/comments.

Comment: Reopen request. I took some time to think about the question which with the help of one of the answers I figured it out. I also posted the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method located in the `RegistrationPage` class you usually need to have an instance of it so the compiler knows which `clickOn` method you are calling.

You can do this without an instance by making the method `static` and then you can call RegistrationPage.clickOn, but changing it to static has other implications that you should read up on.

The other solution is to make RegistrationPage a parent class/interface and have the lower class inherit it, then you can just call `clickOn`; but it doesn't make much sense to have a test class inherit from a non-test class.

Comment: I used the  lower class option. I used the Abstract page to do all of the stuff you would normally write in the test class like find elements and click or find elements and sendkeys. I wanted someone who has very little code knowledge to be able to read the test and have a ok understanding of what the test is doing the only thing thats different about the test is that it's where I make assertions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not extending/inheriting at all, but rather using the `RegistrationPage` class. For this reason, it is necessary to type the `onRegistrationPage` portion, so it is clear to a reader of your code (and to the java compiler) that you are calling a method of `onRegistrationPage` rather than some other object.

If you wanted to revise this code, you could use a single method in `RegistrationPage` or a subclass, where that method takes enough parameters to do all of the `type` and `clickOn` calls with one method call from `Testforpage`.